# How to fix CSS float issues in IE6 and IE7?

Tags: css, internet-explorer

I am talking about the "Previous" and "Next" post navigation links below the articles on my website, which look like this (below) in all modern browsers (IE > 7)

[image]

But in IE6 and IE7, it looks like this

[image]

Yes, the rest of my website looks very fine in these browsers as well, and want to get this to work, and without breaking anything else. I see that IE6 and IE7 can have float issues, and that there's a fix as well (a working one, I couldn't find).

This is the HTML code pertaining to the post navigation (mentioned above):

```
<div class="post-entries">
<div class="nav-prev fl"><a href="http://example.com/2011/01/01/post-1/" rel="prev"><span class="meta-nav">?</span> LG's A530 3D Notebook Shoots And Plays In 3D [PICS]</a></div>
<div class="nav-next fr"><a href="http://example.com/2011/01/01/post-2/" rel="next">LG's Mouse Scanner Saves Scanned Material To Image, PDF or DOC <span class="meta-nav">?</span></a></div>
<div class="fix"></div>
</div>
```

and here's the CSS code pertaining to the above:

```
.post-entries { clear:both; margin-top:20px; background-color: #F8F8F8; border-bottom: 1px dashed #AAAAAA; border-top: 1px dashed #AAAAAA; line-height: 1.7; margin-bottom: 15px; padding: 5px 10px; font-weight: bold; font-size: 1.1em; }
.post-entries a:link, .post-entries a:visited { font-size:0.9em; color:#888; }

.fl{float: left;}
.fr{float: right;}

.fix{clear: both;height: 1px;margin: -1px 0 0;overflow: hidden;}
```

I hope I am clear. Can someone help me out with this?

Comment: Here's a [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/y3MBC/1/) for it...

Comment: That doesn't look all that untoward. I'd be inclined to leave it broken for IE7. But why do you need to support IE6?

Comment: I am actually worried about IE7, but was just mentioning that it's (as obvious as it should) the same in IE6 as well. It does look very untoward for me. My website looks great even in IE6 except for this part. That is what i am worried about. Why leave it?

Comment: Do you want the links to be on the same line horizontally? Or in the position shown in the first image?

Comment: @marissa.c as shown in the first image.

Answer (score 1):

How about this? Added css:

```
/*.post-entries{float:left;width:600px}*/
.nav-prev,.nev-next{display:block;width:100%}
```

Updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/y3MBC/14/

Comment: No post entries can't be limited to a width of 600px - - my post body is 650px, and I have full width posts as well. see: http://bit.ly/o8XCSf

Comment: We're almost there! I added only `.nav-prev,.nev-next{display:block;width:100%}` and it now looks like this in IE7: http://bit.ly/nsiOXJ How can I get the other link into the box (dashed box)?

Comment: try .post-entries{float:left}

Comment: doesn't work. Looks like this now: http://bit.ly/oLLob2 Is it not possible to fix this?

Comment: try .post-entries{width:100%}

Comment: Did it!!! used these: `.post-entries { height: 100%; }` and `.nav-prev, .nev-next {display:block; width:100%; }` , and it's working!!! Please correct me if what I am doing is wrong.

Comment: No, I already tried `.post-entries{width:100%}` before. `height:100%` seems to have fixed my issues. Thanks a lot @marissa.c

Answer (score 0):

I think if you just add a `<div style="clear:left;></div>` in between the two divs it will format the way you want. I tested it in ie7 but don't have an effective way of testing for ie6. Here's the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/D3Jja/

Comment: Unfortunately, that didn't change a thing. :(

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you haven't specified a width for the div's.  Try this:

```
.fl{float: left; width: 100%}
.fr{float: right; width: 100%}
```

Also if you plan on using margin/padding add a `display: inline` to your floated elements to prevent old IE from doubling the amount of margin/padding.

Comment: So you mean to say I should use `.fl{float: left; width: 100%; display: inline;}` and `.fr{float: right; width: 100%; display: inline;}` right?

Comment: you only need the `display: inline` if you plan on adding margin/padding to the element.  If not then you're fine.

Comment: The float alignment is gone with `width: 100%;` I mean when I use `.fl{float: left; width: 100%;}` and `.fr{float: right; width: 100%;}` both lines are aligned to the left. :(

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @marissa.c for the help, this is the answer...

modify this line:

```
.post-entries { clear:both; margin-top:20px; background-color: #F8F8F8; border-bottom: 1px dashed #AAAAAA; border-top: 1px dashed #AAAAAA; line-height: 1.7; margin-bottom: 15px; padding: 5px 10px; font-weight: bold; font-size: 1.1em; }
```

to his:

```
.post-entries { clear:both; margin-top:20px; background-color: #F8F8F8; border-bottom: 1px dashed #AAAAAA; border-top: 1px dashed #AAAAAA; line-height: 1.7; margin-bottom: 15px; padding: 5px 10px; font-weight: bold; font-size: 1.1em; height: 100%; }
```

And then add this line:

```
.nav-prev, .nev-next { display:block; width:100%; }
```

And that fixes the float issues. It now even works in IE6, all credit to @marissa.c